# nhibernate: select parents and newest child

Tags: nhibernate, parent-child, queryover

I have the following entities

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public virtual string InternalNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<VehicleDriverHistory> DriverHistory { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleDriverHistory : HistoryEntity
{
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    public virtual DriverPerson Driver { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to select every Vehicle and, if present, the newest VehicleDriverHistory-Entry according to "Date".
But I'm kinda struggling, I have no problem doing it in sql, but failed in nhibernate so far.

What I have so far:

```
VehicleDriverHistory vdHistory = null;
VehicleDriverHistory vdHistory2 = null;
q.Left.JoinAlias(x => x.DriverHistory, () => vdHistory);
q.Left.JoinAlias(x => x.DriverHistory, () => vdHistory2).Where(x => vdHistory2.Date > vdHistory.Date);
q.Where(x => vdHistory2.Id == null);
```

This doesn't work and it was just my attempt to "translate" the sql query (which yields the correct data) to nhibernate.

So, how would I select parents and the newest child (or none if none is present)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

With Firos help I ended up with the following:

```
VehicleDriverHistory historyAlias = null;
var maxDateQuery = QueryOver.Of<VehicleDriverHistory>()
                   .Where(h => h.Vehicle == historyAlias.Vehicle)
                   .Select(Projections.Max<VehicleDriverHistory>(h => h.Date));

var vehiclesWithEntry = DataSession.Current.QueryOver(() => historyAlias)
                        .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(h => h.Date).Eq(maxDateQuery)
                        .Fetch(h => h.Vehicle).Eager
                        .Future();

Vehicle VehicleAlias = null;
var vehiclesWithoutEntry = DataSession.Current.QueryOver<Vehicle>(() => VehicleAlias)
                           .WithSubquery
                           .WhereNotExists(QueryOver.Of<VehicleDriverHistory>()
                           .Where(x => x.Vehicle.Id == VehicleAlias.Id).Select(x => x.Id))
                           .Future();

return vehiclesWithEntry.Select(h => new PairDTO { Vehicle = h.Vehicle, NewestHistoryEntry = h }).Concat(vehiclesWithoutEntry.Select(v => new PairDTO { Vehicle = v })).ToList();
```

I had to replace the Any() statement in vehclesWithoutEntry with a subquery-clause because it raised an exception.

Comment: Can you post SQL you want, as this will help compile the query as you mention `latest date` but then have `vdHistory2.Date > vdHistory.Date`

Comment: This is the query I tried to translate. But if you have a another suggesstion, just post it ;)

`SELECT
    *
FROM
     vehicles
LEFT OUTER JOIN VehicleDriverHistories AS vdh1 ON
     vdh1.vdh_vehicleId= vehicles.BVE_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN VehicleDriverHistories  AS vdh2 ON
     vdh2.vdh_vehicleId = vehicles.BVE_Id AND
     vdh2.vdh_date > vdh1.vdh_date
     
where vdh2.vdh_vehicleId is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some other idea using Futures to make only one roundtrip

```
VehicleDriverHistory historyAlias = null;
var maxDateQuery = QueryOver.Of<VehicleDriverHistory>()
    .Where(h => h.Vehicle == historyAlias.Vehicle)
    .Select(Projections.Max<VehicleDriverHistory>(h => h.Date));

var vehiclesWithEntry = session.QueryOver(() => historyAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(h => h.Date).Eq(maxDateQuery)
    .Fetch(h => h.Vehicle).Eager
    .Select(h => new PairDTO { Vehicle = h.Vehicle, NewestHistoryEntry = h })
    .Future<PairDTO>();

var vehiclesWithoutEntry = session.QueryOver<Vehicle>()
    .Where(v => !v.DriverHistory.Any())
    .Select(v => new PairDTO{ Vehicle = v })
    .Future<PairDTO>();

return vehiclesWithoutEntry.Concat(vehiclesWithEntry); // .ToList() if immediate executing is required
```

Update: i can not reproduce the exception but you could try this

```
VehicleDriverHistory historyAlias = null;
var maxDateQuery = QueryOver.Of<VehicleDriverHistory>()
    .Where(h => h.Vehicle == historyAlias.Vehicle)
    .Select(Projections.Max<VehicleDriverHistory>(h => h.Date));

var vehiclesWithEntry = session.QueryOver(() => historyAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(h => h.Date).Eq(maxDateQuery)
    .Fetch(h => h.Vehicle).Eager
    .Future();

var vehiclesWithoutEntry = session.QueryOver<Vehicle>()
    .Where(v => !v.DriverHistory.Any())
    .Select(v => new PairDTO{ Vehicle = v })
    .Future<PairDTO>();

return vehiclesWithoutEntry.Select(h => new PairDTO { Vehicle = h.Vehicle, NewestHistoryEntry = h }).Concat(vehiclesWithEntry);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I adapted your sample and it almost works.
But I don't seem to have a concat-method, does it reside in another namespace?

And isn't it somehow possible to something like that (pseudocode)
`.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(h => h.Date).Eq(maxDateQuery).OR(h.Date == NULL)`

Comment: Concat is namespace System.Linq. `.OR(h.Date == NULL)` does not work because if there is no date there is no history record to get the vehicle from no?

Comment: hm, strange. I can't use Concat in the way you do it in your sample. It's only available after I call `vehiclesWithoutEntry.List()`

Comment: did you forget `.Future<PairDTO>()` ?

Comment: yes, I took your query and changed it a bit. I thought that otherwise it would return objects of type PairDTO, wouldn't it?
After that I tried with your exact query. Unfortunately it wouldn't compile, because I can't use 
`.Fetch(h => h.Vehicle).Select(etc.`
The compiler complains that no definition for `Select` is present.

I tried to redesign the query but to no avail

Comment: arg everytime i write off the top of my head i forget to put the eager behind Fetch

Comment: hm, ok, I added fetch, now it compiles but an InvalidOperationException is thrown
`variable 'h' of type 'NOODIS.Entities.VehicleDriverHistory' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`


caused by the line `.Select(h => new PairDTO { Vehicle = h.Vehicle, NewestHistoryEntry = h })`

I don't get it why...

Comment: does it go away when you left out `Vehicle = h.Vehicle,`? if not move the Select in the return statement befor the concat

Comment: unfortunately neither of th two suggestions worked. I tried different approaches. I'm slowly getting frustrated with nhibernate (makes a simple thing pretty hard to accomplish)
Do you have another idea?

Comment: I managed to get it to work, thanks for your help. I updated my question with the solution.